# Creating a list with elements other lists (same struct)

Tags: c, linked-list

Lets say i have 3 lists : list1,list2,list3.

Their `struct` of each element of those lists :

```
struct node {
    char value[20] ;
    struct node * next ;    
    int occurs;
} ;

typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node * List;
```

but i dont think it matters.

I want to create a new list but every element of it has to be each of those 3 lists.My new `struct` for this matter is that(its correct):

```
typedef struct listoflists{
    List list;
    struct listoflists*next;
}Nested;
```

My new function to make the list :

```
void createlistoflists(Nested **LIST,List list1,List list2,List list3){
     if (*LIST==NULL){
         *LIST=listab;
     }
     else
```

So im not sure if the begging is even correct but how will i fill it(and correct) in order to achieve the list of lists?

Comment: If you know how to create and manipulate linked lists already, then what, exactly, is the problem?  I mean, I find some of your names a bit misfit, and it's poor form to disguise pointer nature behind a typedef, but everything you've presented except the inclomplete `createlistoflists()` function looks basically OK.

Comment: I cant link the `LIST`.I dont know how its supposed to be and how to interpret it to write the function.I mean i have a concept in my mind but i 'd like some help in this one

Comment: This question was asked earlier today.  What happened to the previous one?

Comment: Deleted.It was poorly written if i understand from the people approaching who didnt got the point well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Nested* Nested_create(List list) {
    Nested* new = malloc(sizeof(Nested));
    new->list = list;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

void Nested_add(Nested** proot, Nested* node) {
    if (*proot == NULL) {
        *proot = node;
    } else {
        Nested* cur = *proot;
        while (cur->next)
            cur = cur->next;
        cur->next = node;
    }
}

void createlistoflists(Nested **LIST, List list1, List list2, List list3) {
    Nested_add(LIST, Nested_create(list1));
    Nested_add(LIST, Nested_create(list2));
    Nested_add(LIST, Nested_create(list3));
}
```

In a single function:

```
void createlistoflists(Nested **LIST, List list1, List list2, List list3) {
    List lists[] = {list1, list2, list3};
    for (List* it = lists; it < lists + 3; ++it) {
        Nested* node = malloc(sizeof(Nested));
        node->list = *it;
        node->next = NULL;
        *LIST = node;
        LIST = &(*LIST)->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: The `struct` part its diffrent.And i want one separate function.Also the original struct isnt needed....i already have 3 lists ready

Comment: You mean the different name? As for `ThreeListNode` containing three lists you said you want to store three lists for EACH of the elements in the listoflists.

Comment: I said each element has to be each of those lists not all.It means for every element 1 list, i even have the struct

Comment: I modified it, now it's a simple list of lists, it can handle any number of elements, but you can create a convenience function to create one with three lists.

Comment: u have to suppose that the 3 lsits pre exist .its complicated in your code.I have everything on my post.....

Comment: You can copy the `ListNode` struct and `ListNode_*` functions and it's ready for use with your existing code, you can create `ListNode`s using your preexisting lists.

Comment: the point is to call the function once.can it be done?like a foor loop or smthing which creates the list

Comment: Yes, I will modify the solution to better suit you needs

Comment: use my function definition and  use something like current->next=temp,current=current->next

Comment: that is much better but it will be even better if there is a way to make it in 1 function.is there?like if you place certain conditions if&&||