# How do i create a linked list that points to another linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

Im doing this program for managing students enrolled in each subject.
The system is composed by a linked list of subjects and a linked list of students. Each subject has a linked list of pointers for its students. 
Each student has a list of pointers to their respective subjects.
None of the linked lists have headers.
Im trying to create the function to build the list of pointers to the subjects of each student but i dont understand how can i create it.

The structs i have so far are:

```
typedef struct node_subject * ListSubjects;
typedef struct node_subject {
    char *name;
    struct node_ptrStudent *Students;
    ListSubjects next;
}NodeSubject;

typedef struct node_student * ListStudents;
typedef struct node_student {
    char *name;
    int num;
    struct node_ptrSubject *Subjects;
    ListStudents next;
}NodeStudent;

typedef struct node_ptrSubject * ListPtrSubjects;
typedef struct node_ptrSubject {
    ListSubjects subjects;
    ListPtrSubjects next;
}ListPtrSubjects;

typedef node_ptrStudent * ListPtrStudents;
typedef struct node_ptrStudent {
    ListStudents student;
    ListPtrStudents next;
}ListPtrStudents;

void createListPtrSubjects (ListSubjects);
```

Comment: Similar [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881119/creating-a-list-with-elements-other-lists-same-struct).

Comment: I would add as a not-so-off-topic comment: if there were lots of students, or the server were not dedicated or there were any sort of scalability issue, a double linked list may not be the best choice. I would use a hash map / linked list structure instead (a lazy hash should be enough).

Comment: This organization is going to be hell when you start trying to add or, more particularly, drop courses or students.  You'd do better with a database.

Comment: I agree with the comments about the difficulty of handling such a structure, but as an exercise in pointer structures, it may be adequate. To begin with, what is your input? Do you have to make several passes over the input? What lists can you build first, and then use for the remaining lists? Some answers depend on what is given to you, some on your own choices.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel style says *"It’s a mistake to use typedef for structures and pointers."* https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs; whether or not one agrees with this, I think you have to many `typedef`; it's kind of confusing.

If you were programming a relational database, which you kind of are, this would be an associative entity; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity. Also, make sure that your subjects have a primary key.

For example,

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_ realloc */
#include <limits.h> /* INT_MAX */
#include <errno.h>  /* errno */
#include <stdio.h>  /* perror printf */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */

struct Subject {
    int id; /* Primary key. */
    const char *name;
    struct Takes *takes_head;
};

struct Student {
    int id; /* Primary key. */
    const char *name;
    struct Takes *takes_head;
};

/* (Weak) Associative entity. */
struct Takes {
    int subject_id, student_id; /* Compound key. */
    struct Takes *next_subject, *next_student;
};

static struct School {
    struct Subject *subjects;
    int subjects_no;
    struct Student *students;
    int students_no;
} school;

static struct Subject *lookup_subject(const int id) {
    if(id >= school.subjects_no) return 0;
    return school.subjects + id;
}

static struct Subject *add_subject(const char *name) {
    struct Subject *subjects, *s;
    assert(name);
    if(school.subjects_no == INT_MAX) { errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    /* fixme: realloc is slow; eg, double capacity. */
    if(!(subjects = realloc(school.subjects,
        sizeof *school.subjects * (school.subjects_no + 1)))) return 0;
    school.subjects = subjects;
    s = school.subjects + school.subjects_no;
    s->id = school.subjects_no;
    s->name = name;
    s->takes_head = 0;
    school.subjects_no++;
    return s;
}

/* May output in a static buffer. */
static const char *subject_to_string(const int id) {
    struct Subject *const subject = lookup_subject(id);
    static char str[256] = ""; /* Static buffer. */
    if(!subject) { sprintf(str, "<subject id %d>", id); return str; }
    return subject->name;
}

static struct Student *lookup_student(const int id) {
    if(id >= school.students_no) return 0;
    return school.students + id;
}

static struct Student *add_student(const char *name) {
    struct Student *students, *s;
    assert(name);
    if(school.students_no == INT_MAX) { errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    if(!(students = realloc(school.students,
        sizeof *school.students * (school.students_no + 1)))) return 0;
    school.students = students;
    s = school.students + school.students_no;
    s->id = school.students_no;
    s->name = name;
    s->takes_head = 0;
    school.students_no++;
    printf("%s is assigned id %d.\n", s->name, s->id);
    return s;
}

/* May output in a static buffer. */
static const char *student_to_string(const int id) {
    struct Student *const student = lookup_student(id);
    static char str[256] = ""; /* Static buffer. */
    if(!student) { sprintf(str, "<student id %d>", id); return str; }
    return student->name;
}

static struct Takes *lookup_takes(const int student_id, const int subject_id) {
    const struct Student *const student = lookup_student(student_id);
    struct Takes *t;
    if(!student) return 0;
    for(t = student->takes_head; t && t->subject_id != subject_id; t = t->next_student);
    return t;
}

static struct Takes *add_takes(const int student_id, const int subject_id) {
    struct Subject *const subject = lookup_subject(subject_id);
    struct Student *const student = lookup_student(student_id);
    struct Takes *t = lookup_takes(student_id, subject_id);
    printf("%s enrols in %s.\n", student_to_string(student_id),
        subject_to_string(subject_id));
    /* Already have it. */
    if(t) return t;
    /* Or else make a new. */
    if(!subject || !student) { errno = EDOM; return 0; }
    if(!(t = malloc(sizeof *t))) return 0;
    t->subject_id = subject_id;
    t->student_id = student_id;
    t->next_subject = subject->takes_head, subject->takes_head = t;
    t->next_student = student->takes_head, student->takes_head = t;
    return t;
}

static void print_subject(const int subject_id) {
    struct Subject *const subject = lookup_subject(subject_id);
    struct Takes *t;
    printf("_Subject: %s._\n", subject_to_string(subject_id));
    if(!subject) return;
    for(t = subject->takes_head; t; t = t->next_subject)
        printf("%s takes %s.\n", student_to_string(t->student_id),
        subject_to_string(t->subject_id));
}

static void print_student(const int student_id) {
    struct Student *const student = lookup_student(student_id);
    struct Takes *t;
    printf("_Student: %s._\n", student_to_string(student_id));
    if(!student) return;
    for(t = student->takes_head; t; t = t->next_student)
        printf("%s takes %s.\n", student_to_string(t->student_id),
            subject_to_string(t->subject_id));
}

int main(void) {
    const char *why = 0;
    do { /* Try. */
        struct Subject *subject;
        struct Student *student;
        int herbology_id, defense_id, potions_id;
        int hermione_id, ron_id, harry_id;

        why = "Herbology";
        if(!(subject = add_subject(why))) break;
        herbology_id = subject->id;
        why = "Defense";
        if(!(subject = add_subject(why))) break;
        defense_id = subject->id;
        why = "Potions";
        if(!(subject = add_subject(why))) break;
        potions_id = subject->id;
        why = "Hermione";
        if(!(student = add_student(why))) break;
        hermione_id = student->id;
        why = "Ron";
        if(!(student = add_student(why))) break;
        ron_id = student->id;
        why = "Harry";
        if(!(student = add_student(why))) break;
        harry_id = student->id;
        why = "enrol";
        if(!add_takes(hermione_id, defense_id)
            || !add_takes(hermione_id, potions_id)
            || !add_takes(hermione_id, herbology_id)
            || !add_takes(ron_id, herbology_id)
            || !add_takes(harry_id, potions_id)) break;
        print_subject(herbology_id);
        print_subject(defense_id);
        print_subject(potions_id);
        print_student(hermione_id);
        why = 0;
    } while(0); if(why) perror(why); /* Catch. */
    /* fixme: free memory in 'final' block. Remember to free Takes. */
    return why ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```